# Color entire Bootstrap menubar when mobile (hamburger menu) is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a menubar that I want to add some CSS or JS to. I want to make it such that when I click on it when in responsive view, the entire object can be targeted (I plan to do some background styling). I've found some stack overflows re: coloring the menu items, the menu itself, but none of those when applied to the overall menubar either A) work at all B) work only for responsive, which is what I want.

I've made a [codepen](http://codepen.io/Er-c/pen/amBwRa). I just can't figure out if things like `:active` or `:focus` or something else would be the right fit. Hopefully the code pen illustrates what I want. I just cannot seem to target the navbar in it's entirety whether thru JS or CSS. I want to achieve a background effect for not just the dropdown but the row the hamburger lives in when clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Bootstrap's collapse events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-events)**.

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse', function () {
  // Do your stuff
  // This event fires immediately when the show instance method is called.
});

$('.navbar-collapse').on('hide.bs.collapse', function () {
  // Do your stuff
  // This event is fired immediately when the hide method has been called.
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/jrVLwz)

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this to your navbar-header div:

```
<div onClick="clickMe()" class="navbar-header page-scroll">
```

then add this as a function:

```
function clickMe(){
   if(window.innerWidth < 768){
    $('.navbar-header').css('background-color', 'red');
  }
}
```

it will work.   you can also do an addClass('className'), and specify the class name like so:

```
.navbar-header.className{
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much